# Where have the full package descriptions gone?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, apt-cache

Once upon a time, if I wanted to know what a particular (uninstalled) packages was for, I could go

`apt-cache show <package>`

and it would produce a slew of information, including a good couple of paragraphs describing the package.

This has changed recently.  Now the "Description" field is only ever one line.

On an older, system, It goes:

```
mslade@natty1:~$ apt-cache show apt
[snip]
Description: Advanced front-end for dpkg
 This is Debian's next generation front-end for the dpkg package manager.
 It provides the apt-get utility and APT dselect method that provides a
 simpler, safer way to install and upgrade packages.
 .
 APT features complete installation ordering, multiple source capability
 and several other unique features, see the Users Guide in apt-doc.
```

And now:

```
mslade@mickpc:~$ apt-cache show apt
[snip]
Description: commandline package manager
```

The long descriptions are still in the package files, and you can query them with `dpkg -s` if you've already *installed* them, but this isn't helpful if you just want to know more about some package that was mentioned on some web site.

I have searched everywhere for some source for these descriptions.  The best I have some up with so far is, download the .deb file and run `dpkg-deb -I` on it.  This is really overkill if all you want is the metadata.

Is there a better way?

Update: I just installed a new pangolin VM and noticed its `apt-cache show` gave long descriptions, *until* i fudged `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use my own mirror, produced with debmirror.  I suspect debmirror is the culprit.

Comment: I still see more than one line. I see what you see in the "older system". This is on Lubuntu 12.10. And this is also for software that I haven't installed (but are available).

Comment: I also tested this on a system running Ubuntu Raring (what will eventually be released as 13.04) and I do get a long description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `--i18n` to debmirror has fixed this.

This is an ubuntu quirk.  Debian's `Packages` files contain the long english descriptions, ubuntu has pulled them out into `Translation-en` files.  debmirror assumes you only need translation files if you want something besides english, so it doesn't mirror any by default.

(Is this worth keeping as a question/answer?)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like you have something like

```
Acquire::Languages { "none"; };
```

somewhere in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

Replace it by

```
Acquire::Languages { "environment"; };
```

or

```
Acquire::Languages { "en"; };
```

You may need to run

```
apt-get update
```

to download to corresponding translation files (`/var/lib/apt/lists/*Translation-*`)

Comment: No, nothing of the sort.  See question edit.

Comment: That answer is so perfectly right for me.

Comment: Perfect, worked in the case where I was running in a Docker container.  The docker version of Ubuntu has a conf file called docker-no-languages with Acquire::Languages "none"; in it, changing "none" to "environment" and running sudo apt update worked a treat.